# DOS escape characters in unix files

Tags: bash, unix, escaping, character, dos

I have a script that I wrote on my (US) mac (osx 10.8.4), which works great.  I then e-mailed it to someone with another (european) mac (osx 10.8._), and it complains that:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
```

at a handful of blank lines, and at the end of a `case` statement.  No where else.

[I found this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/623501/shell-script-error-using-cygwin), and eventually what solved the problem was using a code called `dos2unix`.

My question is: *where did these `DOS` escape characters come from?!*

---

Process:
I created the program in emacs via Terminal.app.  I attached it to an e-mail in Mail.app and sent it.  Also tried opening it in textedit, selecting all the text, copying and pasting into a Mail.app e-mail.  Did the same things (attachment and copy and paste) in Gmail (using a via chrome browser), same problem.

---

The script in question (with `***` added at lines with errors):

```
#!/bin/sh
                                                                          ***
DIR="mhd_3/"
APP="/Users/lzkelley/Applications/athena/athena4.1/vis/vtk/join_vtk"
FNAME="lzk_flux-cap-1"
LOG_FLAG=False
                                                                          ***
# --- Check for Command Line Arguments ---
                                                                          ***
while getopts hp:s:i:f:l: opt; do
    case "$opt" in                                                        ***
        #p) NUM_PROCS=$OPTARG;;
        #s) NUM_SNAPS=$OPTARG;;
        i) DIR=$OPTARG;;
        f) FNAME=$OPTARG;;
        l) LOG_FLAG=True; LOG=$OPTARG;;
        h) usage;;
        \?) printf "Invalid Option!\n"; usage;;
    esac
done
                                                                          ***
printf "\nprocess_vtk.sh\n\n"
                                                                          ***
# Make sure directory ends with slash
DIR=$(echo "$DIR"|sed 's/\/$//g')                                                                   # Remove slash if it has it
DIR=$DIR/                                                                                           # Add slash

NUM_PROCS=$(find $DIR -type dir -name "id*" | wc -l)                                            # Use word count to find num directories matching (id*) in output folder
NUM_SNAPS=$(find $DIR'/id0/' -name "$FNAME*.vtk" | wc -l)                                       # Use word count to find num vtk files in target directory


# Adjust numbers for loops (i.e. 0 to [NUM-1] )
let "NUM_PROCS -= 1"
let "NUM_SNAPS -= 1"

# Iterate through each snapshot
for NS in `seq 0 $NUM_SNAPS`; do
    printf -v jj ".%04i." $NS                                                                       # Assume 4 digit numbering
    OUTNAME=$DIR$FNAME".all"$jj"vtk"                                                                # Construct output filename from directory, file name base, and number
    INNAMES=""                                                                                      # Names of input vtk files (for each processor)

    # Iterate through each processor
    for NP in `seq 0 $NUM_PROCS`; do

        # Names are slightely different for 0th processor
        if [ $NP = 0 ]; then
            THIS=$DIR"id"$NP"/"$FNAME$jj"vtk"                                                       # Name of single vtk file
            if [ -e "$THIS" ]; then
                INNAMES=$INNAMES$THIS                                                               # Append to list
            fi
        else
            THIS=$DIR"id"$NP"/"$FNAME"-id"$NP$jj"vtk"                                               # Name of single vtk file
            if [ -e "$THIS" ]; then
                INNAMES=$INNAMES" "$THIS                                                            # Append to list
            fi
        fi
    done # NP

    echo $APP -o $OUTNAME $INNAMES

    # Call the program to merge vtk files
    $APP -o $OUTNAME $INNAMES


done # NS
```

Comment: Copy/paste, mail user agent, ... there are many possibilities.

Comment: @devnull why would copy paste do that?  Also, attached the file without copying and pasting - and problem persists.  Tried both via Mail.app and GMail; both as attachment and copy/paste

Comment: mail user agents often do funny things.

Comment: Those are both entirely unhelpful comments.

Comment: How exactly did you email it? Using what program and what procedure? And then how did the receiver extract it, with what program and procedure? Perhaps more importantly, if you do an `od -c` on your original script file, do you see `\r` characters at the end of the error lines?

Comment: @mbratch added procedure to question

Comment: Thanks. Did you check the original file for the `\r`? If you find the lines with `\r` there, at least that would factor out the whole email process and narrow it down to the question of how the `\r` was inserted. What's the history of the script? Were pieces previously copy/pasted out of a DOS-originated file perchance?

Comment: @mbratch doing neither emacs search for `\r` nor grep show any results for the file.

Comment: Last ditch: see if `od -c myscript.sh` shows anything. If a copy to email inserted `\r` I would think it wouldn't be too selective about which lines it did it on.

Comment: @mbranch (interesting - haven't seen that command before!) Still nothing from `od` (with visual inspection for `\r` and piping to `grep` (i.e. `od -c myscript.sh | grep '\\r'`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that white space will be preserved in an e-mail. Different MTAs will make modifications, as will clients when you copy and paste between plaintext and what is often HTML in the client.

If you want to ensure the script is the same on both ends your best bet is to compress it and send it in binary form.